# How to make a character body deform on wall (or any surface)

Tags: physics

I started blender 1 month ago and i have not found a single tutorial about making the body of a rigged character deform when pushing against a surface,i have not found tutorials about rigged character physics interacting with objects at all,alll i found are the same videos for "how to break walls with a cube" and stuff like that,can you help me?

i would normally do the effect on photoshop for a single picture but it's for animation

Comment: isn't that called physics or something?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gYsxqNJyu8 i found this vid